# Why does my threaded Perl script segfault?

Tags: linux, multithreading, perl, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a curses script which requires cleanup after processing SIGINT in order to return the terminal back to its original status.

I get a segfault when the signal handler is enabled.

For support's sake, I removed all the curses code to boil the problem down.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;

sub cleanup { exit 0; }

sub run { while (1) {} }

# comment this line and the problem disappears
$SIG{INT} = \&cleanup;

foreach my $i (1..100) {
    print "Creating this thread\n";

    my $t = threads->create(\&run);

    print "Created that thread\n";
}

while (1) { print "Looping\n"; }
```

Sample Error Trace (segfaults 90% of the time):

```
$ ./threadtest.perl

...

Creating this thread
Creating that thread
Detaching this thread
Detaching that thread
Creating this thread
^CSegmentation fault

$
```

Specs:

- threads 1.72
- archname ""
- os ""
- Perl 5.10.1 (came with Debian) Debian
- 6 Squeeze

Initial Impression:

I think the problem occurs when the custom signal handler grabs control. This somehow prevents the next thread from being created, resulting in a segfault.

Does Perl's default SIGINT handler run special code to safely end evaluation of thread creation? If so, I imagine the solution is to copypasta into the custom handler.

Comment: Does the following snippet cause a segfault: perl -e "sub M::DESTROY; bless {}, M;" ( If so, you need to see if there's an updated 5.10.1 ) -- your script works fine on a 5.10.1 w/o that bug

Comment: That does not segfault for me on Perl 5.10.1. What are your system specs?

Comment: mcandre: Code works fine in my Perl 5.12.3.

Comment: @Alan Good. Can someone verify for Debian (repositories don't have 5.12.x), Mac OS X (MacPorts has 5.12.2), and Windows (ActiveState Perl 5.12.3)?

Comment: mcandre: Works in Perl 5.10.1 (Ubuntu 10.10).

Comment: For posterity, what `threads->VERSION` and what `$Config{archname}` ?

Comment: "perlbrew switch" has no effect on Debian or Ubuntu. Did you compile v5.12 yourself?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce this with the perl 5.10.1 that is included in Ubuntu 10.10. threads 1.74.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem on 5.10.1 in Ubuntu 10.10 with threads 1.72

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [revision history for the `threads` module](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JDHEDDEN/threads-1.82/Changes) contains:

```
1.73 Mon Jun  8 13:17:04 2009
- Signal handling during thread creation/destruction (John Wright)
- Upgraded ppport.h to Devel::PPPort 3.17
```

which suggests that there was a known problem with signal handling during thread creation and destruction in versions earlier than 1.73. Upgrade your `threads` module.